# How to skip the first whitespace match in regex [Python]?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas 'read_csv' function to read the lines of a file which is not in a CSV format. It does not contain ',' (comma) for me to use it as the delimiter. It has whitespaces with different spacings. The line below is one of the example:

```
Power Output 12(25%)   24(50%)  12(25%)
```

I would like to extract them out using the following way `pandas.read_csv(sep='')` by using regex and I'm not sure how exactly it can be done. I know I can separate them using whitespaces but that will separate `Power Output` as two different columns. I want a regex method where I can match all the whitespaces irrelevant of the spacing, BUT skips the first match it founds.

I'm expecting the following output in the pandas dataframe later:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Power Output | 12(25%) | 24(50%) | 12(25%) |

Comment: You can match the regular expression `r'^\w+ \w+| +(\d{2}\(\d{2}%\))'`. If a match does not save anything to capture group 1, return the match (`'Power Output'` in the example); if the match saves a string to capture group 1 return the contents of the capture group (e.g., `'12(25%)'`, the match being `' 12(25%)'`). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KkGbWB/1). Alternatively, remove the capture group and return matches after striping leading spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use white spaces followed by a digit as separator. For this use a look-ahead regex:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., sep='\s+(?=\d)', engine='python')
```

Output:

```
              0        1        2        3
0  Power Output  12(25%)  24(50%)  12(25%)
```

Alternative regex, split by any group of spaces that is not followed by a non-digit: `'\s+(?!\D)'`

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses `sep=''` (empty string). You want to use `sep='\s+'` (regex for whitespace).

If you want more detail, refer to the documentation for read_csv:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: This does not answer the question. They're asking about using `sep=''` regex that skips the first occurrence of space(s), and then proceeds to delimit between an uneven number of spaces.